# how to retry api call 3 times in angular until get the data ( only 1 API , not generic to http interceptor )

Tags: angular, rxjs, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

in my app module i have call this provider

```
export function appConfigFactory(configService: AppConfig) {
  return () => configService.getEasyAuthToken();
}
 { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appConfigFactory, deps: [AppConfig],  multi: true }
```

and AppConfig file look like below :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfig {
  public settings: any = null;
  public initialized = "authentication in progress";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getEasyAuthToken() {
    let aHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const url = '/.auth/me';
    console.log(`on app load ${url} called`);
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(url, { headers: aHeaders })
      .pipe(
        tap((config: any) => {
          console.log(config);

        }).error(this.initialized = "authentication failed";)
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

Question #1 : sometimes when i am calling config /.auth/me i got reponse as empty array just : [], so i want to try 3 times api call if response is empty.
( extra info about /.auth/me here => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims)

Question #2 : how to write failed or error block in above call with pipe?

Question #3 : when call is failed or response if empty after 3 times api call, i want to show different text something like "authentication failed" in app.component.html. - via `this.initialized` variable

Comment: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/retry-failed-http-requests-in-angular-f5959d486294

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `retry(num)` operator, see the code below

```
return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(url, { headers: aHeaders })
      .pipe(
        tap((config: any) => {
           if(!config.length) {
             this.initialized = "authentication failed";
             throw 'authentication failed';
           }
        }),
        retry(3)
      )
      .toPromise();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more complicated but more flexible solution:

```
  public getEasyAuthToken() {
    //...
    const url = '/.auth/me';
    console.log(`on app load ${url} called`);
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(url)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          if (!res) // or other check if your responce is empty
          {
            // error will be picked up by retryWhen
            throw res;
          }
          return res;
        }),
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            mergeMap((err, i) => {
              console.log(err, i);
              const retryAttempt = i + 1;

              if (retryAttempt > this.maxRetryAttempts) {
                // Maximum number of retries reached
                this.initialized = "authentication failed";
                return throwError(err);
              }

              return timer(retryAttempt * 1000);
              }),
          )
        ),
        catchError(error => {
          // Use catchError to prevent breaking of your observable sequence
          console.error(error);
          return of(error);
          })
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

Many companies use similar approach in production.
You can play with it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z83mdi